# carrierwave backgrounder with delayed jobs taking too much time to upload

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, carrierwave

I am working with Rails4, carrierwave, carrierwave_backgrounder, and delayed_job_active_record.

I have followed the exact procedure but it's taking to much time,
[carrierwave_backgrounder](https://github.com/lardawge/carrierwave_backgrounder),
[Procedure Doc](http://www.acnenomor.com/2071887p2/rails-carrierwave-backgrounder-with-delayed-jobs-taking-too-much-time-to-upload)

Any valid suggestions...

Comment: Can we see your code? Also, how big is the file being uploaded?

Comment: Size of file is only 250KB. Delayed job is working but to inserting row into delayed_job table it's taking time.

Comment: How much time is the database insert taking?

Comment: Around 30 to 40 seconds... If i use delay jobs also taking 25 to 30 sec.